# Why Uniqueness Explains Method Of Images

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, conductors, method-of-images

Why does uniqueness of Poisson equation guarantee that method of imaging works?

If say, we find a distribution that matches the boundary potential (thus matches the boundary condition) we still need to make sure that our potential that arises from this distribution still satisfies Poisson equation to make sure that we found the solution to the boundary value problem, however for us to be able to do this we need to know the charge density, which we don't actually know do we? So then how can we check that our "trick" actually gave us the sought for potential, since we cant actually verify it satisfies Poisson equation.

I.e we would like to check: $\nabla^2V=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ but how do we know $\rho$ if we don't know the charge distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the method of images is used when the charge distribution is known. You're handed some configuration of charges in some region with a conducting boundary, and your job is to find the potential. The method of images gives you a potential with the same charge distribution in the region of interest, but with the conducting boundaries replaced by some extended region containing additional "image" charges. Since the charge distribution is the same as the original problem in the region of interest, and since the solution to Poisson's equation is unique, you have then successfully found the potential.

Comment: say in the classical example of a plane and a charge a distance above the plane. Once we used the method of images and got the potential, what is $\rho$ that we have so that we can check that our V satisfies $\nabla^2 V = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$

Comment: As stated, you have to assume from the start that $\rho$ is known. In electrostatics, the problem is almost always stated as, "Here is some configuration of charge $\rho(\vec{r})$ and some boundary conditions. What is the electric potential in the region surrounding the charge?" For example, if you happen to be working out of Griffith's book, the section on the method of images on page 124 starts: "Suppose a point charge $q$ is held a distance $d$ above an infinite grounded conducting plane. Question: what is the potential in the region above the plane?" In other words, $\rho$ is given to you.

Comment: so in that case $\rho = 0$ outside the plane and has a singularity at the point charge ? however we don't know $\rho$ on the plane. Also in Griffiths, he doesn't check that the given potential actually satisfies the poisson equation, he just asserts that its right since it matches the boundary conditions

Comment: Ah, I see the question: yes, the charge distribution on the plane is not a priori specified. However, it's easy to determine using $\sigma = - \epsilon_0 \partial V / \partial n$ (equation 2.49 of Griffiths). Griffiths could check that the given potential actually satisfies the Poisson equation, but you don't need to: it's the potential generated by two point charges, so of course it satisfies Poisson's equation.

Comment: Right I see what you are saying, however it still seems quite sketchy to me, you are finding the charge density $\rho$ (at least on the plane) **after** you have found the potential, how did you find this potential: by using an imaginary charge distribution. So now you have a potential, how do you know it is correct ?  Well it does satisfy boundary conditions, now I gotta check it satisfies $\nabla^2 V = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$, oops, It seems I don't know $\rho$ (at least on the plane).

Comment: You cant use $\sigma$ as you calculated since in that calculation you used the thing that you actually need to find, namely $V$, so that $\sigma$ is yet again an imaginary $\sigma$ that occurs from the imaginary charge distribution, you have no guarantee its right for the **real** conductor. Im not sure if you get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: To put it another way, Say you are a mathematician and you want to find V simply by solving $\nabla^2 V = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ you cant even start since you are not given $\rho$ everywhere (the boundary say).

Comment: The reason you don't need $\rho$ at the boundary is because you are already given the boundary conditions in the form of the potential. In PDEs, specifying the potential is known as a Dirichlet boundary condition, whereas specifying the charge (which thereby specifies $dV/dn$) is known as a Robin boundary condition. If you specified both, then your system would be overconstrained, and there would be no solution.

Comment: Perhaps if I specified the problem more carefully, your concern would be alleviated: given $\rho(\vec{r})$ in the region $z > 0$ and the boundary condition $V(z=0) = 0$, find $V(\vec{r})$ in the region $z > 0$. In other words, you are indeed given $\rho$ everywhere, since the region of interest is $z > 0$. The charge at the boundary is found by the additional physical assumption that the region $z \leq 0$ is a conductor (or mathematically, that $V(z \leq 0) = 0$), but you don't need any knowledge of this charge if your goal is to find the potential in the region $z > 0$.

Comment: Ah okai it makes sense now, All in all my concern was that in all these exercise they dont give me $\rho({\bf r})$  and I was confused why they dont give it to me and I concluded that maybe we dont know it and then I got to this conceptual paradox that I wrote about in this post... So to end this helpful discussion; in the plane example, if we were in vacuum and there was only one charge above plane, would $\rho({\bf r}) = 0$ for ($z>0$ and not at point charge) and $\rho({\bf r}) = \infty$ at the point charge ?

Comment: Kind of. More accurately, $\rho(\vec{r}) = q\, \delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)$, where $q$ is the charge of the point charge, $\vec{r}_0$ is its location, and $\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)$ is the Dirac delta function. In case you are not familiar, you can roughly think of it as a function which is zero everywhere except $\vec{r}_0$, where it is infinite, and integrating over the function gives 1.